# If statement always ends up in one state

Tags: excel, vba

I Have an Excel spreadsheet with column A formated as date `03-Mar` I am trying to create a macro to show a msgBox if the wrong month is entered.

The problem with this is the msgBox shows either way

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim M As String
    Dim W As String
    M = May
    W = Apr
    If ActiveCell = W Then
        MsgBox ("Wrong Month entered")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf ActiveCell = M Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: May and Apr are being treated as variables which are blank. The value of ActiveCell must also be blank. Put quotes around May and Apr and see what happens.

Comment: Format is irrelevant. Look up how dates are stored in Excel. Try something like `select case month(activecell.value): case 4: msgbox "wrong month": case 5: some code: case else: some other code`

Comment: Make sure you use `Option Explicit` • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

`May` and `Apr` is considered as variables (they are empty). Therefore your code cannot work. Make sure you use `Option Explicit`, this will immediately show such issues.

Also dates are stored as numbers in Excel. The number is the amount of days since `1900-01-01`. So today is `2022-03-07` and Excel stores this as `44627` which means todya is `44627` days since `1900-01-01`. So the actual value in the cell is `44627` and if you use `.NumberFormat` to format it, Excel just shows something else like in your case `03-Mar` but the cell value is still a number.

So if you want to find out wich month a numeric date is you can use the `Month()` method, and since `May` is month `5` you can easily test for that:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' exit if more than one cell was changed
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Month(Target.Value) <> 5 Then  ' If month not may then messagebox
        MsgBox "Wrong Month entered"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PEH I tried that but the message box still appears on both entries. Any ideas

Comment: Add `Debug.Print Target.Value` and `Debug.Print CDbl(Target.Value)` to that code and tell what the output in the immediate window is.